# How to check if text value is in a control's DataSource which contains DataRowViews?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

On validating a ComboBox I'm trying to check if the value in the ComboBox is in the list of values that is databound to said ComboBox.
The datasource is a BindingSource and the underlying items are of type DataRowView.
So I can't figure out how to compare the combobox's value to the 'Person' field of the DataSource's DataRowView

Also before someone suggests just setting the DropDownStyle to DropDownList, that is not an option for this case.

What I have tried:

```
private void ddPerson_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmbo = sender as ComboBox;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddPerson.Text))
        {
            if (cmbo.Items.Contains(ddPerson.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(cmbo, "");
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(cmbo, "\"" + person.Text + "\" is not in the list of accepted values");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(cmbo, cmbo.DisplayMember + " is required");
        }
    }
```

I've also tried

`if (personBindingSource.Contains(ddPerson.Text))`
The above two solutions I tried don't work because personBindingSource and cmbo.Items are just lists of DataRowView objects.

And from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24126821/3490417
I tried
`if (cmbo.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Select(x => Convert.ToString(x["Person"]).Contains(ddPerson.Text))`
This doesn't compile with error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'

EDIT:
I found an alternate way of checking if the combobox's value is in the combobox's bindingsource. Though I ended up using [mm8's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54201970/3490417) solution as it is cleaner.

```
int found = personBindingSource.Find("Person", ddPerson.Text);
if (found < 0)
{ errorProvider1.SetError(cmbo, "\"" + person.Text + "\" 
  is not in the list of accepted values"); }
```

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, can you show the DataSource for ddPerson?

Comment: Not really as it is databound to a dataset table. But I can tell you the only fields in said table are 'ID' and 'Person'

Comment: If you have the ValueMember set to "ID", them you can just check `if (ddPerson.SelectedValue == null)` then you don't have something in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (cmbo.Items.OfType<DataRowView>().Any(x => x["Person"]?.ToString() == ddPerson.Text))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work regardless of the data-bound item type and the display member property:

```
var isValid = cmbo.Items.Cast<Object>().Any(x=>cmbo.GetItemText(x) == ddPerson.Text);
```

Comment: To get the display value of items, it's almost always better to use `GetItemText`.